# How can I trigger an action without clicking a button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a text input to enter some text and search it on google.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type search word and press Enter to google" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="search" onClick="javascript:
window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("btn").click();
  }
});
</script>
```

I want to get rid of the search button and integrate the googling function only through pressing Enter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nj2mq5vu/)

Using a form and ES6 syntax is the easiest and most efficient method:

```js
const $form = document.getElementById('form')
const $input = document.getElementById('input')

$form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  window.open(`https://google.com/search?q=${$input.value}`)
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google" id="input" />
</form>
```

Comment: Upvoting since it's a good answer. But the run code snippet part doesn't seem to do anything when I press enter in the text input, which makes it useless. I'd consider getting rid of that, especially since you provided the fiddle link which *does* work.

Comment: @paxdiablo if you press enter in the text input and open your browser console, you will see the following error: `Blocked opening 'https://google.com/search?q=' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`, which proves that the example is working. The error occurs because the Stack Snippet is being hosted on a different domain, [stacksnippets.net](https://stacksnippets.net).

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/t1djucrx/2/

```
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();   
   window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + document.getElementById('text').value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to completely remove the button, then instead just put the code from the button in a javascript function, and call that when enter is pressed, so

```
<input type="text" placeholder="press Enter to google" id="text" />


<script>
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + document.getElementById('text').value);
  }
});
</script>
```